# How to set emacs indentation level in function

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

I don't understand emacs, but I have the following function in a file:

```
;;; File: emacs-format-file
;;; Stan Warford
;;; 17 May 2006

(defun emacs-format-function ()
   "Format the whole buffer."
;;;   (c-set-style "stroustrup")
   (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
   (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
   (delete-trailing-whitespace)
   (save-buffer)
)
```

I then run this function in a batch script.  Here's the code snip:

```
echo "Indenting $1 with emacs in batch mode"
emacs -batch $1 -l $eprog_format -f emacs-format-function
echo
```

I use this code to format my c/c++ files and headers.  I like to change it so that I can hardcode the level of indentation into the function, that way I can run this code to conform to whatever indentation rule for whatever company I am currently writing code for.  Or pass it in as argument?

I just don't know how to do this.  Is there a way?  My current .emacs has:

```
; Suppress tabs.
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

I don't want to add indentation levels in my .emacs.  I like to keep the default emacs indentation.  I want the emacs script to customize the indentaion before I "ship it ".

thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to Emacs, but perhaps astyle would be better suited for this task.

Comment: Hey that is cool.  I will check it out.  But, I'd like an answer to my original Q, because I just need a slight tweak to my work flow.  astyle could possibly be the way to go, but I'm not sure what other 'habits' I'll need to adopt.  If you know what I mean.  Anyways, this looks like a great suggestion, and I will kick the tires on it.  So thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the variable `c-basic-offset` and a `let` binding. Here is an example of how `let` works:

```
    (setq original "Hello")

    (message "%s" original)
    "Hello"

    (defun temp-set-var (arg)
      (let ((original arg))
        (message "%s" original)))

    (temp-set-var "Goodbye")
    "Goodbye"

    (message "%s" original)
    "Hello"
```

Even though I called `(message "%s" original)` three times, it outputted a different string the second time because I temporarily set `original` to `arg` in the function with `let`.

So maybe your format function could be:

```
    (defun emacs-format-function (indent)
      "Format the whole buffer."
    ;;;   (c-set-style "stroustrup")
      (let ((c-basic-offset indent))
        (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil))
      (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
      (delete-trailing-whitespace)
      (save-buffer))
```

Then call it like:

```
emacs -batch $1 -l $eprog_format --eval="(emacs-format-function 8)"
```

Comment: Cool.  I tried copying the new function and running my script, but I keep getting the error \(emacs-format-function\ 4\) is void.

Comment: Probably because of that backslash. `emacs -f` can't take arguments, you'll have to use `--eval` as I did.